# Remove from history unsynced git commit that is not last one

Tags: git

Currently the best solution that I found is

```
git reset --soft HEAD^2
```

to keep wanted changes

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

to kill unwanted commit

unfortunately it will force me to recreate commits made after one that I want to disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `git rebase -i <target commit>^`

Then when presented with the list of commits to rebase, delete the line for the commit you want to remove.

For example, if I have:

```
6e99176 most recent commit
60dd2f0 older commit
4c82808 even older commit
b980abe commit i want to remove
5b7254b oldest commit
```

I can do

```
git rebase -i b980abe^
```

And will be presented with:

```
pick 6e99176 most recent commit
pick 60dd2f0 older commit
pick 4c82808 even older commit
pick b980abe commit i want to remove

# Rebase 50ce3f5..9ad75f8 onto 50ce3f5
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

If you follow the instructions and remove the offending commit, then save and close the file, you will have removed that commit from your git history.